# SqlAlchemy: Sub-Select with a Dual EXISTS (OR) and an additional boolean check

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SqlAlchemy I need to implement the following subquery, which runs fine in PostgreSQL. It is an OR condition consisting of 2 EXISTS, plus an additional AND block. That whole column results in a True/False boolean value.

```
SELECT
...
...
,

(SELECT 
    (
        EXISTS (SELECT id from participating_ic_t pi1 where pi1.id = agreement_t_1.participating_ic_id 
                AND pi1.ic_nihsac = substr(ned_person_t_2.nihsac, 1, 3))
     OR EXISTS (SELECT id from external_people_t ep1 where ep1.participating_ic_id = agreement_t_1.participating_ic_id 
                AND ep1.uniqueidentifier = ned_person_t_2.uniqueidentifier)
    )
    AND ned_person_t_2.current_flag = 'Y' and ned_person_t_2.inactive_date is null and ned_person_t_2.organizationalstat = 'EMPLOYEE'
) as ACTIVE_APPROVER1,
```

First of all, if I omit the additional AND block, the following OR-EXISTS by itself works OK:

```
subq1 = db_session.query(ParticipatingIcT.id).filter((ParticipatingIcT.id == agreement.participating_ic_id),
                                                     (ParticipatingIcT.ic_nihsac == func.substr(approver.nihsac, 1, 3)))
                                             .subquery()
subq2 = db_session.query(ExternalPeopleT.id).filter((ExternalPeopleT.participating_ic_id == agreement.participating_ic_id),
                                                    (ExternalPeopleT.uniqueidentifier == approver.uniqueidentifier))
                                            .subquery()                                     
subqMain =  db_session.query(or_(exists(subq1), exists(subq2))
                      .subquery()

# ...
# Now we will select from subqMain.                   
agreements = (db_session.query(
                   ..,
                   subqMain
```

But the problem starts when I introduce the final AND block. Conceptually, the final result should be the following:

```
subqMain = db_session.query(and_(
                                or_(exists(subq1), exists(subq2)), 
                                approver.current_flag == 'Y',
                                approver.inactive_date == None, 
                                approver.organizationalstat == 'EMPLOYEE'))
                      .subquery()
```

But this actually emits `" .. FROM APPROVER_T"` **right in the sub-query**, whereas it should be linked to the `FROM APPROVER_T` of the **main** query at the very end. I need to avoid adding the `.. FROM [table]` which happens as soon as I specify the `and_(..)`. I don't understand why it's doing that. All subqueries are specifically marked as `subquery()`. The alias `approver` is defined at the very top as `approver = aliased(NedPersonT)`.

Comment: Does using `subq1.exists()` instead of `exists(subq1.subquery())` make any difference?  [sqlalchemy.orm.Query.exists](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.exists)

Comment: No, that actually gives the error `AttributeError: 'Subquery' object has no attribute 'exists'`

Comment: In place of subquery it gives that error?

Comment: It gives it if I do `subq1.exists()`

Comment: I posted an untested answer to try and clarify what I mean.  If you can post a simplified version of your table schema it would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wasn't working with that Sub-Select so I rewrote it as a **CASE statement** instead. Now it's working. Also, I had to join on a couple of extra tables in the main query to facilitate this new CASE.

```
casePrimaryApprover = case(
    [
        (and_(
            (agreement.approving_official_id.is_not(None)),
            (approver.current_flag == 'Y'),
            (approver.inactive_date.is_(None)), 
            (approver.organizationalstat == 'EMPLOYEE'),
            or_(
                (participatingIc.ic_nihsac == func.substr(approver.nihsac, 1, 3)), 
                (externalPeoplePrimaryApprover.id.is_not(None))
            )
        ), 'Y')
    ],
    else_ = 'N'
)


# Main Query
agreements = (db_session.query(
    agreement.id,
    ...
    casePrimaryApprover 
    
    ...
    .join(participatingIc, agreement.participating_ic_id == participatingIc.id)
    .outerjoin(externalPeoplePrimaryApprover, approver.uniqueidentifier == externalPeoplePrimaryApprover.uniqueidentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
exists1 = db_session.query(
    ParticipatingIcT.id
).filter(
    (ParticipatingIcT.id == agreement.participating_ic_id),
    (ParticipatingIcT.ic_nihsac == func.substr(approver.nihsac, 1, 3))
).exists() # use exists here instead of subquery
exists2 = db_session.query(
    ExternalPeopleT.id
).filter(
    (ExternalPeopleT.participating_ic_id == agreement.participating_ic_id),                                                  
    (ExternalPeopleT.uniqueidentifier == approver.uniqueidentifier)
).exists()  # use exists again instead of subquery                                     

subqMain =  db_session.query(and_(
    or_(exists1, exists2),
    approver.current_flag == 'Y',
    approver.inactive_date == None, 
    approver.organizationalstat == 'EMPLOYEE')).subquery()

# ...
# Now we will select from subqMain.                   
agreements = (db_session.query(
                   OtherModel,
                   subqMain))
```

[sqlalchemy.orm.Query.exists](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.exists)

## Half Baked Example

I also use aliased here because I don't quite understand the method of operations concerning wrapping sub queries in parentheses.  It seems to work without it but the RAW sql is confusing to read.  This is toy example I made to try and see if the SQL produced was invalid.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    hobbies = relationship('Hobby', backref='user')

class Hobby(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hobbies'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable = False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
with Session(engine) as session:
    user1 = User(name='user1')
    session.add(user1)
    session.add_all([
        Hobby(name='biking', user=user1),
        Hobby(name='running', user=user1),
        Hobby(name='eating', user=user1),
    ])
    user2 = User(name='user2')
    session.add(user2)
    session.add(Hobby(name='biking', user=user2))
    session.commit()


    nested_user = aliased(User)
    subq1 = session.query(Hobby.id).filter(nested_user.id ==Hobby.user_id, Hobby.name.like('bik%'))
    subq2 = session.query(Hobby.id).filter(nested_user.id ==Hobby.user_id, Hobby.name.like('eat%'))
    subqmain = session.query(nested_user).filter(or_(subq1.exists(), subq2.exists()), nested_user.id > 0).subquery()
    q = session.query(User).select_from(User).join(subqmain, User.id == subqmain.c.id)
    print (q)
    print ([user.name for user in q.all()])
```

```
SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name 
FROM users JOIN (SELECT users_1.id AS id, users_1.name AS name 
FROM users AS users_1 
WHERE ((EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM hobbies 
WHERE users_1.id = hobbies.user_id AND hobbies.name LIKE %(name_1)s)) OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM hobbies 
WHERE users_1.id = hobbies.user_id AND hobbies.name LIKE %(name_2)s))) AND users_1.id > %(id_1)s) AS anon_1 ON users.id = anon_1.id
['user1', 'user2']
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'm currently trying to rewrite this with a CASE statement which should be simpler, with whatever extra joins are required. Once finished I'll post an answer here.